# Is the Go! action card ever worth playing?

Tags: monopoly-deal

In Monopoly Deal, there is a Go! Card which uses one of your three plays for the turn in order to draw two additional cards. It seems the key to winning in this game revolve around emptying your hand to draw 5. Let's start from that scenario:

```
turn x  : draw 5, play 3, leaves 2 in hand
turn x+1: draw 2, play 3, leaves 1 in hand
turn x+2: draw 2, play 3, leaves 0 in hand
```

So with this we have 3 turns, 9 cards, or an average of 3 cards per turn.

Now let's say we play a go:

```
turn x  : draw 5, play 2 and a go, leaves 5 in hand
turn x+1: draw 2, play 3, leaves 4 in hand
turn x+2: draw 2, play 3, leaves 3 in hand
turn x+3: draw 2, play 3, leaves 2 in hand
turn x+4: draw 2, play 3, leaves 1 in hand
turn x+5: draw 2, play 3, leaves 0 in hand
```

So now, in six turns, we've instead managed to draw 17 cards over 6 turns, or 2.8 cards per turn. So we see FEWER cards per turn if we play a go, plus one less action.

Should I be using my goes for money instead to maximize the number of cards I see?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to cards, it is very important to consider tempo when deciding what moves to make in a variable-hand-size card game... if your hand is strong enough on its own merit without having to draw additional cards, that's great, but you're going to run into situations where playing the 'Go' as a money card and playing another card already in hand is not going to be as good as playing the 'Go' card as an action card and then playing one of the cards that were drawn by the 'Go' action.

I would say that the only time that you should play the 'Go' card as money EVERY TIME is when it is the last card in your hand, and the last action you can take (but even then you're only betting that the 5 cards you'll draw at the beginning of your next turn are better than the four cards that you'd draw if you played the go card and drew two your next turn.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea to play an action card for money (except if you run out of money of course). It may serve at one moment of the game. So do not play your goes card for money. It may gives you a second wind to your hand with two brand new cards which enables you to build a new strategy. Imagine that in the two new cards there are cards like "Deal Breaker" or other cards which could be combined with another of your hands to get lots of money or properties. Is it better to get only 1M in your bank ? Not so sure...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does! Because if you still have 3 or 2 turns and have run out of cards to play, put down your 'Go' card and you get 2 extra cards you can put down!

Playing the 'Go' card as money is fine too, but as @air-dex said:

> This is a bad idea to play an action card for money (except if you run out of money of course).